# print all the strings possible of length k from a given string with repition allowed usibg arraylist

Tags: java, string, recursion, arraylist

Given a string S and an integer k, you need to find and return all the possible strings that can be made of size k using only characters present in string S.
The characters can repeat as many times as needed.

```
import java.util.*;
public class Solution {
    public static String[] allStrings(String charSet, int len) {    
        // Write your code here 
        HashMap<Character,Boolean> map=new HashMap<>();
        for (int i=0; i<charSet.length();i++){
            if(!map.containsKey(charSet.charAt(i))){
                map.put(charSet.charAt(i),true);
            }
        }
        ArrayList<Character> al=new ArrayList<Character>();
        for (Map.Entry<Character,Boolean> entry:map.entrySet()){
            al.add(entry.getKey());
        }
        ArrayList<String> real=new ArrayList<String>();
        String pre="";
        perm(pre,al,len,real);
        String []a=new String[real.size()];
        a=real.toArray(a);
        return a;
    }

    public static void perm(String pre,ArrayList<Character> al,int k,ArrayList<String> real) {
        if(k==0){
            real.add(pre);
            return;
        }
        for(int i=0;i<al.size();i++){   
            pre=pre+al.get(i);
            perm(pre,al,--k,real);
        }
    }
}
```

Here I am getting stack overflow error @

```
pre=pre+al.get(i);
perm(pre,al,--k,real);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two issues here:

```
pre=pre+al.get(i);
perm(pre,al,--k,real);
```

1. You make this recursive call `al.size()` times, and each time you decrement `k`. Since `k` is initialized to the length of the desired `String`s, if `k < al.size()`, it will eventually become negative, and the recursive call will never terminate (since it terminates only when `k==0`).
2. Before each recursive call, you add a character to `pre`, but you don't remove the character added in the previous iteration. Therefore you'll end up with output `String`s longer than the desired length.

You can fix the issues as follows but keeping `pre` and `k` unchanged:

```
public static void perm(String pre,ArrayList<Character> al,int k,ArrayList<String> real)
{
    if(k==0){
        real.add(pre);
        return;
    }
    for(int i=0;i<al.size();i++){
        perm(pre+al.get(i),al,k-1,real);
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot, man!!!, you solved a huge problem in my competitive career.

Comment: thanks a lot again.. i there any option of being friend or following you